# Weird CPU usage drop after Start-Sleep in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, while-loop, sleep, cpu-usage, amd-processor

This code right here takes ~20% of my CPU usage (AMD FX 6300):

```
$test1 = "Test 1"
$test2 = "Test 2"
$test3 = "Test 3"
$test4 = "Test 4"

do {
if ($test1 -eq "Test 1"){Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss"; Write-Host ""; Write-Host "OK."}
if ($test2 -eq "Test 2"){Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss"; Write-Host ""; Write-Host "OK."}
if ($test3 -eq "Test 3"){Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss"; Write-Host ""; Write-Host "OK."}
if ($test4 -eq "Test 4"){Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss"; Write-Host ""; Write-Host "OK."}
} While($true)
```

... I was trying to reduce program's CPU usage while running. I also noticed that adding a `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50` at the beginning of the `Do - While` statement reduces it by ~100%... Anybody knows why this happens?

Comment: Think about it this way. (Bear with me on this analogy): you have an egg you're cooking on one stove burner, and one on another burner. As long as the pan is on the stove (`while($true)`), continue to cook the egg. As for the other egg, you pick up the pan continuously and hold it away from the flame for 15 seconds each time. Which egg do you think is gonna cook faster? Which pan is hotter? You're essentially giving the your script a break (hence why cpu usage drops), vs having it constantly running.

Comment: Hopefully that analogy makes sense lol

Comment: I also recommend looking into the `switch` statement, along with `splatting`.

Comment: Haha, what an analogy! @AbrahamZinala. We could say that technically, by removing the `Start-Sleep` statement, the script is taking 100% of processor time on one thread. Here you can see an example of what happens with 2 `while($true){ }` loops: https://imgur.com/f2ssNrv

Comment: By adding the `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50` what is happening is that the time taken to evaluate the 4 `if statements` is significantly lower (by a big amount in this case) than the `50 Milliseconds` where your OS can allocate time to other processes running, hence the lower CPU consumption.